# Private methods in certain scenarios in Java

Tags: java, junit4

The general answer is not to test private methods. So my question is for a scenario that I am working on. I have a method that should do the following :

1. public Collection submit(Collection values)
2. It does the following - Call services - update API
3. I have a private method that will sync Ids after values are submitted
4. (3) is achieved using a private method syncAfterSubmit(Collection beforeSubmit, Collection afterSubmit)
5. My problem is I do not want it to be called other than through submit and I would also like to unit Test my syncAfterSubmit method.

What are my options here ?

Comment: Use reflection or don't make it private.

Comment: youre describing one of the problems in Java for testing private methods. Like mentioned, you'll have to use reflection. Too bad Java doesn't have the equivalent of the C++ friend class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guava has an annotation for that called

> @VisibleForTesting

where they make a method `protected` for example instead of private, *for the sole reason of testing*.

Comment: Yes , but it does not seem to work with Junit4. Does it need more settings ?